# JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

I'm getting a *"Cannot read property of undefined"* error in the following code.

What happens is that the `initFromServer()` is called which goes to get the model from the server.  But what ends up happening is that when `init()` is called, the parameter model is undefined. Using `console.log` to determine what is going on it seems that it never reaches the `Proxy.getModel()` function before it determines that model is undefined.

I'm not entirely sure what is going on.  There are a lot of other functions and what not that I have not inserted.  Hopefully it makes sense.

```
ClientModel.prototype.initFromServer = function(success) {
    this.getProxy().getModel(this.init(), success());
}

ClientModel.prototype.init = function(model) {  
    this.setMap(new catan.models.Map(model.map.radius));    
};
```

In the proxy file we have:

```
Proxy.prototype.getModel = function(update, success) {
    jQuery.get("/game/model", function(data) {
                    update(data);
                    success(data);
    });
};
```

Comment: So you have defined an `init()` method with 1 argument and don't pass any when you invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `init()` in `initFromServer()` you do not pass any arguments.

In the `init()` function you access `model` as first argument …

```
ClientModel.prototype.initFromServer = function(success) {
    this.getProxy().getModel(this.init(), success());
                                       |
                                       +---- No Argument.
}

ClientModel.prototype.init = function(model) {
                                       |
                                       v
    this.setMap(new catan.models.Map(model.map.radius));
                                       |
                                       +----> Ups.
};
```